# netbeans not displaying form correctly

Tags: java, netbeans

I Netbeans when I run my program it shows my buttons like this:
[image]

Left side is how it should look. Right hand side is how it's showing up when I run the file. anyone know what's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have Java installed? Flash, etc? Try installing them. (Just an idea - this probably isn't the problem.)

Comment: Could you post an SSCCE?

Comment: @muntoo, Netbeans is running, so why would installing Flash or reinstalling Java help?

Comment: @jzd No idea, just an *idea*. [Doesn't hurt to try, does it?](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Comment: Looks more like a font problem to me. Try changing one JLabel to a non exotic common font and see if appears correctly in the preview.

Comment: hi.i've used the same font etc in other forms. and it works. and i've changed the font and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing a clean and build project the problem has disappeared. It must just be a cache type of thing as many of my labels started to do this aswell.